# Easy Notation for Optional Addition to an Object?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, object

I have a service with some optional inputs that are passed in depending on which form is calling the service. If I try and run this without the sid an eid inputs, the actual .add({}) to firestore with an error about undefined for the field, which makes some sense.

> Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field eventId in document

So, I can think of several ways using various expressions and if statements, or writing 2 different variations on the service that can be called from the different locations, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Is there an easy way, like the '?' you can use in interfaces or in inputs to indicate that this field is optional?

like: { ...inventoryAdd, ...timestamp, ...?sessionId, ...?eventId }

Or, do I just need to write some logic, or split out the function into two?

```
  addInventory(inventoryAdd: any, pid: string, sid?: string, eid?: any) {
    const inventoryCollectionRef = this.afs.collection("/Party-Management/" + pid + "/Party-Inventory");
    const timestamp = { timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() }
    const sessionId = { sessionId: sid}
    const eventId = { eventId: eid }
    inventoryCollectionRef.add({ ...inventoryAdd, ...timestamp, ...sessionId, ...eventId })
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably just use `if` statements (but keep reading):

```
addInventory(inventoryAdd: any, pid: string, sid?: string, eid?: any) {
    const inventoryCollectionRef = this.afs.collection("/Party-Management/" + pid + "/Party-Inventory");
    const toAdd = {
        ...inventoryAdd,
        timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    };
    if (sid) {
        toAdd.sessionId = sid;
    }
    if (eid) {
        toAdd.eventId = eid;
    }
    inventoryCollectionRef.add(toAdd);
}
```

But if you want to do it with expressions instead, spreading `null` is a no-op, so you could set `sessionId`/`eventId` to `null` when you don't have `sid`/`eid` (see `***`):

```
addInventory(inventoryAdd: any, pid: string, sid?: string, eid?: any) {
    const inventoryCollectionRef = this.afs.collection("/Party-Management/" + pid + "/Party-Inventory");
    const timestamp = { timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() };
    const sessionId = sid ? { sessionId: sid} : null;   // *** 
    const eventId = eid ? { eventId: eid } : null;      // ***
    inventoryCollectionRef.add({ ...inventoryAdd, ...timestamp, ...sessionId, ...eventId });
}
```

Spreading `undefined` is also a no-op, as is spreading an empty string, so you could also do it like this (see `***`):

```
addInventory(inventoryAdd: any, pid: string, sid?: string, eid?: any) {
    const inventoryCollectionRef = this.afs.collection("/Party-Management/" + pid + "/Party-Inventory");
    const timestamp = { timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() };
    const sessionId = sid && { sessionId: sid};   // *** 
    const eventId = eid && { eventId: eid };      // ***
    inventoryCollectionRef.add({ ...inventoryAdd, ...timestamp, ...sessionId, ...eventId });
}
```

That works because `x && y` evaluates `x` and if `x` is [*falsy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) takes the value as its result, otherwise it evaluates `y` and takes that as its result. So if `sid`/`eid` is `undefined` or `""`, `sessionId`/`eventId` is `undefined` or `""` (and spreading them doesn't put anything in the object); otherwise, they're the objects and spreading them adds their properties to the object.

Comment: Really helpful comment, I appreciate the detail you went into. Setting the value to null instead of undefined was certainly an elegant solution, and it works great. I went with option #2, and I want to look at option #3 some more so I can better understand the logic.